# How to assign Angular Service object to $scope object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I'll try to keep this as simple as possible.

I have a controller for State 1 that saves a form object(with several fields) to the Service array upon submit and then proceeds to the state 2.

On the next page there is a back button to go back to state 1. I want the user to be able to go back and the ng-model fields to populate with what was saved. This  is the function I have in my controller.

```
var setForm = function(){
    if (estateSvc.forms[0]){
    $scope.personalform = estateSvc.forms[0];
    }
}
setForm()
```

Using `console.log($scope.personalform)`. I was able to see that the `estateSvc.forms[0]` was properly assigned to `$scope.personalform`. But, for example, the `ng-model="personalform.example"` input field does not update with `estateSvc.forms[0].example`.

Controller

```
.controller('personalCtrl', function ($scope, estateSvc) {   
$scope.personalform = {};
var setForm = function(){
    if (estateSvc.forms[0]){
            $scope.personalform = estateSvc.forms[0]
    }
}
setForm()

$scope.addForm = function(form, number){
    estateSvc.addForm(form, number)
}

});
```

Service

```
.service('estateSvc', function () {
// AngularJS will instantiate a singleton by calling "new" on this function
var estateObject = {};

estateObject.forms = []

estateObject.addForm = function(form, number){
    estateObject.forms[number] = form
}

return estateObject

});
```

Any suggestions on how to assign the Service object to the $Scope object and have the ng-model populate?

Comment: Try to remove the setForm function, and assign directly `$scope.personalform = estateSvc.forms[0];`

Comment: What Medet said, or add the `setForm` method to `$scope`. i.e. `$scope.setForm = function() { ... }; $scope.setForm();`.

Comment: Thank @Lex and @Medet Tleukabiluly . I tweaked it and refreshed a bunch of times and did what you said with function.`var setForm = function() {if (estateSvc.forms[0]) { return estateSvc.forms[0] } else { x = {}; return x } }  $scope.form = setForm()`